# Spring Data : Embedded /Non embedded?

Tags: deployment, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data for Neo4j and MongoDB, I find it awesome, but now I just found out about the embedded and not embedded DB stuff.

**Here's my situation :**

- Using Spring Data with the annotations, repositories, templates and thinking that I just need to change the DB address to make it work elsewhere.

**My questions :**

- 1) I don't even understand what they mean by embedded vs non embedded (on the same machine vs on a distant machine ?)
- 2) Do I have to change all the work I've done to make it work with a 'non embedded' DB ?

What I wan't to do is to deploy my Spring Boot app that is using Neo4j to Heroku or CloudFoundry and use Graphen (Neo4j paas) for the DB. But when I saw all this story about Spring Data working only for embedded, I just lost all the hope and happiness I had when building my app.

- 3) If 2) is Yes, is it an easy transition ? is there a lot of things to change ?

**EDIT :** 
Here's what I'm talking about :

http://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/extending-the-neo4j-server-with-spring-data-neo4j/

He's adding some custom boilerplate code to make it work with a non embeded DB, is it ok ? Why it doesn't work as any other DB (like with JPA, where you just specify the address of the DB).

Comment: Sure you can run embedded (fast) and remote/restful (less fast) what does your Spring configuration look like at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inserpio here. Don't lose your happiness, please: Spring Data Neo4j team is working hard to implement a new release that improves remote performances.

When Spring Data Neo4j started neither Cypher nor Neo4j-Server existed, while only the embedded version was available. As the server version was delivered SDN team provided a quick  solution that works well if you only use repositories, but becomes a little bit too chatty is you want to use @Entity too. The problem is matching those @Entity with the returned nodes.

Since the new version is still not completed, for the moment, you could move you persistence-logic more tight to the database as a server extension. I explained it on the link you mentioned. It's a really fast refactoring: just move your entities and repositories to a new simple java project, install the resulting jar in the 'plugins' folder, one line configuration in the neo4j-server.properties and expose your queries as simple REST services.

Hope this could help.

Do not hesitate to contact me for any further question.

Cheers,
Lorenzo

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the problem.
The problem I have is that if I want to use a remote DB like Graphene, I don't know if I can implement what I want on their DB server.

Comment: Yes! Of course you can! Keep following the instruction on my blog and of course contact GrapheneDB team! All you have to do is simply upload your jar file, containing the extension, in the plugin section of your instance.